# Node.js callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning node, and one thing I can't seem to figure out is callback signatures. It seems that most callbacks are typically of the form

```
function myCallback(err, doc)
```

which makes sense. But then I come across some other modules, like node-easyimage, which casually mention examples with different signatures, like

```
function myCallback(err, stdout, stderr)
```

There is no mention of which APIs expect which format of callbacks, so I end up digging through the code. But given that callback signatures are almost never mentioned; I feel like there is an unspoken rule that I haven't read. Is there?

Comment: Hate to break it to you but I don't think there is. It is all going to depend on the library you are using. Best you can probably hope for is that the library is at least consistent.

Comment: There's a standard, a DE FACTO standard. If the callback returns an error, the first parameter should be the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no standard approach unfortunately, so you'll just have to get accustomed to the techniques each package uses. This is a general Javascript issue and not just node.js, which is why [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) for example has such appeal.

Answer (score 2):

While it is true that there is no **standard**, the Node community is slowly coalescing around a convention of `callback(error, results)`, where `results` could be a String, Array, Object, etc. depending on the API.